# using MATLAB to find the height of a sphere

Tags: matlab

This is a MATLAB example question.
using MATLAB, find the height (h) of a spherical cap in the equation `(p/3) * pi *h^2 * (3*r - h) - f = 0`.  When `r = 30, f = 4.5, p = 1.027`.

Is this answer correct?

```matlab
r = 30;

f = 4.5;

p = 1.027;

pi = 3.142;

fun = @(h) (p/3)*pi*h^2*(3*r - h) - f;

h = f zero(fun, [0 r]);

display(['The height of the spherical cap is ', num2str(h), ' units.']);
```

Comment: Please read the description before using a tag. Only one of those tags is relevant to your question.

Comment: To answer your question: If you fill in the `h` you found back into the equation in the question, do you get an equality? If so, then the `h` you found is correct, and the code likely is too. If not, then the code is not correct.

Comment: Your code seems almost correct, but there's a small typo in the fzero function call. The correct function name is fzero, not f zero.